# What are all the characters that should be escaped from a string to avoid SQL injection attacks in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am writing a small helper library that is constructing some SQL and executing that against a  SQL Server database.

I know that the best approach is to use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings but this is not an option here because I have the requirement to log all the queries that are executed against the database in a plain human readable manner so that when viewed by an admin they are free to see what the actual values that were used to search for are in the `where` clause.

What are all the characters that I must escape before putting that string in a query and executing it?

I know that the single quote `'` is a must but do I have to care about something else?

Here is some sample code:

```
var condition = new Condition();
var table = new PersonTable();
condition.Add(table.Name.IsEqualTo("John's"));
```

this will be converted to

```
WHERE [dbo].[Person].[Name] = N'John''s'
```

How do you attack that if I'm accepting only `string` in `IsEqualTo` method and escaping the single `'` with `''`?

As far as I know SQL Server accepts only `'` for a string delimiter.

Comment: Why is the best approach "not an option"?

Comment: In order to answer this question and help you solve your problem, we need to know why you can't use parametrized queries, so that we can be sure we help you fix your issue without causing more.

Comment: That's because we have the requirement to store/log the query "as is" and we are not allowed to use any "obscure" stuff that will hide the actual value of the parameters instead of the varbinary/image/ and the very "big" ones that would take too much space to be logged.

Comment: @mcl then you should ask how to log the query in sql server instead of this question

Comment: Where are you doing this logging? Code? On SQL server? What sort of data are queries being run against? Why the requirement and what does that requirement say exactly (notwithstanding any business specific terms that are not Germaine)?

Comment: Why does it matter where I am logging that "script string"? We are using log4net with all sorts of appenders. We log it to a file, to sql server database, we even have a custom appender for logging in mongodb.

Comment: @mcl it matters greatly. If you're logging on the code side, you could always set up a delegate to log what the user tried to search for, and *then* parameterize your query for the database, and you could also log the query in the database, resulting in no extra code on the application side and no danger of opening another attack vector for your application.

Comment: @mcl which database are you using? You have 2008 and 2012 tagged.

Comment: @George Stocker I know the min version of SQL Server that can possibly be used is Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: Also in future we may have the requirement to encrypt that query string and send it over to another server over the internet for remote execution. So I can't use parameterized queries guys. I know that this it the best approach I've been building db apps for quite some time.

Comment: Using parametrized queries is truly the ***ONLY*** viable approach. Don't even start to try to espace that stuff yourself ... you're guaranteed to have more or less holes in your algorithm. Don't waste your time trying to do that - use **parametrized queries - ALWAYS!**

Comment: @mcl: We're trying to help you. Take it from someone with experience, if you're encrypting the querystring for security, you will fail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491603/why-encrypt-query-strings-in-asp-net

Comment: Instead of wasting your time on trying to "sanitize" your inputs just so you can log the composed query without *obscure* features (love that!) - you should better invest your time in enhancing your logging so you can **handle** parametrized queries there! That would be the much safer way of doing things, and the better investment of your time

Comment: Listen to what everybody says, we're not stupid and your logging requirement is not something new. Logging can be done very simple and clean. Take a look at the **FormatCommand** methods here https://github.com/sapiens/SqlFu/blob/master/src/SqlFu/Utils.cs  It ouputs everything you might need from a query: sql and parameters values

Answer (score 9):

Every single character in any known character set.

Now use the proven and accepted techniques.

Comment: Little Bobby tables should use Parameters.

Comment: Please be so kind to read the question again. It has some further clarifications.

Answer (score -3):

You should escape the following characters:

```
'-' because of '--' (comment)
'=' because of 1=1
'>' or '<' because of 1>0
'%' because of Like '%%'
char(39) because of it is equivalent to ' 
'"' because it can use in delimiters
'[',']' because it can use in delimiters
```

Comment: What's the source for this answer? if it's MSDN or some other site, it'd be helpful to have a link to that site as well, just in case there's more information there.

Comment: A strange list. Why do you recommend escaping `=` but not `;`? Actually AFAIK `'` *is* the only one required for values being inserted into the middle of a quoted string literal but I wouldn't want to rely on being correct.

Comment: Following your edit why would `1=1` be a problem but `1 > 0` OK? Also what about entirely legitimate use of `=` in queries. Such as searching for a string containing `=`?

Comment: Thanks every one.You are right but this is just as i experienced.